# subfigure environment for 10 figures

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I am trying to put 10 figures using subfigure environment. I use 4x3 matricx to do that...but the last figure comes at the bottom of the page instead of going to the new page.

What can be done?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_1}
    \caption{Mode-1}
    \label{fig:m1}
\end{subfigure}
    \hspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_2}
    \caption{Mode-2}
    \label{fig:m2}
\end{subfigure}
        \hspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_3}
    \caption{Mode-3}
    \label{fig:m3}
\end{subfigure}\\
 \vspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_4}
    \caption{Mode-4}
    \label{fig:m4}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_5}
    \caption{Mode-5}
    \label{fig:m5}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_6}
    \caption{Mode-6}
    \label{fig:m6}
\end{subfigure}\\
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_7}
    \caption{Mode-7}
    \label{fig:m7}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_8}
    \caption{Mode-8}
    \label{fig:m8}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_9}
    \caption{Mode-9}
    \label{fig:m9}
\end{subfigure}
  \newpage
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \input{Figures_matlab/md_10}
    \caption{Mode-10}
    \label{fig:m10}
\end{subfigure}
  \caption{Mode shapes 1-10}
\label{md_shps}
\end{figure}[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: A `figure` environment cannot split. You would need something like `\ContinuedFloat` from the `caption` package.

Answer (score 3):

Similar question are quite often here (TeX.Se site), so it will be probably designate as duplicate ...

Your last figure *had to be* at bottom of other sub figures, since all are in the same float. *Float can not span two pages*! If you like to have last image on the next page, than you had to make *two* figures: in the first 3 x 3 images and last on the second. But why you should do this? It is enough place to have all images on the same page even if you enlarge them as I do:

[image]

You also can slightly reduce space between rows with images (now is to my taste to large). Since I haven't your images, I use `example-image` from package `mwe` to simulate them.

Code is slightly modified your code. Main difference is that I eliminate (worthless in your case) `\newpage` command in it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-1}
    \label{fig:m1}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-2}
    \label{fig:m2}
\end{subfigure}
        \hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-3}
    \label{fig:m3}
\end{subfigure}

    \vspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-4}
    \label{fig:m4}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-5}
    \label{fig:m5}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-6}
    \label{fig:m6}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-7}
    \label{fig:m7}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-8}
    \label{fig:m8}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-9}
    \label{fig:m9}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Mode-10}
    \label{fig:m10}
\end{subfigure}
  \caption{Mode shapes 1-10}
\label{md_shps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```